# What is difference between these functions?

Tags: go

What difference between the following functions?

```
func DoSomething(a *A){
    b = a
}

func DoSomething(a A){
    b = &a
}
```

Comment: Take the Tourt of Go.

Answer (score 1):

First function receives [pointer](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1) to value of type `A`. Second receives copy of value of type A. Here's how you call first function:

```
a := A{...}
DoSomething(&a)
```

In this case `DoSomething` receives pointer to original object and can modify it.

And here's call for second function:

```
a := A{...}
DoSomething(a)
```

In this case `DoSomething` receives copy of `a`, so it can't modify original object(but if original object contains pointers to other structs it can modify them)

Answer (score 0):

```
func DoSomething(a *A) { // a is a pointer to given argument of type A
    b = a // b is a copy of a, which is also the same pointer

    // this is useful to change the given object directly
}

func DoSomething(a A) { // a is a copy of the given object type A
    b = &a // b is the pointer of a
}
```

Remember, a pointer is a variable which holds a memory address.